# How to convert Gensim corpus to numpy array (or scipy sparse matrix) efficiently?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gensim

Suppose I have a (possibly) large corpus, about 2.5M of them with 500 features (after running LSI on the original data with gensim). I need the corpus to train my classifiers using scikit-learn. However, I need to first convert the corpus into a numpy array. The corpus creation and classifier trainer are done in two different scripts.

So the problem is that, my collection size is expected to grow, and at this stage I already don't have enough memory (32GB on the machine) to convert all at once (with `gensim.matutils.corpus2dense`). In order to work around the problem I am converting one vector after another at a time, but it is very slow.

I have considered dumping the corpus into svmlight format, and have scikit-learn to load it with `sklearn.datasets.load_svmlight_file`. But then it would probably mean I will need to load everything into memory at once?

Is there anyway I can efficiently convert from gensim corpus to numpy array (or scipy sparse matrix)?

Comment: One quick note: since you have performed LSI, you now have dense data. So there isn't much point in going for a scipy.sparse matrix output. A numpy array will use less memory for data that is fully dense.

Comment: yea, needed to find a way to do it fast, if possible (and am scratching head now because I couldn't reproduce the out of memory problem when converting the whole corpus)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very knowledgable about Gensim, so I hesitate to answer, but here goes:

Your data does not fit in memory so you will have to either stream it (basically what you are doing now) or chunk it out. It looks to me like `gensim.utils.chunkize` chunks it out for you, and you should be able to get the dense numpy array that you need with `as_numpy=True`. You will have to use the sklearn models that support `partial_fit`. These are trained iteratively, one batch at a time. The good ones are the [SGD classifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier) and the [Passive-Aggressive Classifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.PassiveAggressiveClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.PassiveAggressiveClassifier). Make sure to pass the classes argument at least the first time you call `partial_fit`. I recommend reading the docs on [out-of-core scaling](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html#scaling-with-instances-using-out-of-core-learning).

Comment: LOL, I was experimenting with chunkize yesterday and I totally overlooked as_numpy *facepalm*, yea, it is already using partial_fit (am replacing some of the components from scikit-learn -> gensim)